# Haskell lens getter that compares values of two lens getters

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I try to write a comparison operator greater-than-equals for two [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4) getters with type

```
(.>=.) :: Ord a => Getting a s a -> Getting a s a -> Getting Bool s Bool
```

I have a working solution for a getter on the left side and a value on the right side (no `.` on the right side of the operator `.>=`)

```
left .>= right = left . to (>= right)
```

I tried

```
left .>=. right = (>=) <$> use left <*> use right
```

but it has type

```
(.>=.) :: (Ord a, MonadState s f) => Getting a s a -> Getting a s a -> f Bool
```

How can I get the desired return type `Getting Bool s Bool` instead of `f Bool`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close with this:

```
λ> left .>=. right = (>=) <$> use left <*> use right
(.>=.) ::
  (Ord a, Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState s f) =>
  Getting a s a -> Getting a s a -> f Bool
```

First, use `view` in instead of `use`; `use` is for getting from state (hence the `MonadState` constraint), which doesn't seem relevant here.

```
λ> left .>=. right = (>=) <$> view left <*> view right
(.>=.) ::
  (Ord a, Control.Monad.Reader.Class.MonadReader s f) =>
  Getting a s a -> Getting a s a -> f Bool
```

That gives you a function (`MonadReader s f => f Bool` specializes to `s -> Bool`), so now you need to turn this into a `Getting` with `to`.

```
λ> left .>=. right = to $ (>=) <$> view left <*> view right
(.>=.) ::
  (Ord a, Contravariant f, Profunctor p) =>
  Getting a s a -> Getting a s a -> Optic' p f s Bool
```

(And `(Contravariant f, Profunctor p) => Optic' p f s Bool` specializes to `Getting Bool s Bool`, so this is what you want.)